# Hibernate: No identifier specified for entity (yes, I have decorated with @Id...)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I have searched all over the place and it seems almost all answers for this problem tell me to annotate either my id property or getter with @Id. I have tried both with absolutely no luck. Here is my entire class thats failing: http://pastebin.com/Cpsdx2Rj
and the following is my exception: http://pastebin.com/uhs9e81b

As I said, I already tried moving the @Id devorator to the property and that doesnt seem to do anything at all.

Any suggestions on what to try? Any other configuration files needed to debug?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: Put the annotation on the variable that might help. I also suspect a classpath issue, try excluding the jpa-api jar (or include it as a provided dependency). Also you are mixing different spring versions (3.2.3 and 3.1.4) so I would strongly suggest you fix your maven pom. Could you tell us the versions of libraries and the server you use?

Comment: Have you possibly annotated getters and fields? Cause you can't do that. It's either getters or fields. Not sure if you posted the whole class so it's a guess

Comment: Few things I may suggest by looking at your stack trace and entity, as mentioned by @M.Deinum, you have mixed version of spring. As well can you show your bean configuration for entityManagerFactory as well its depednacy..as seems you have correct set of annotation for entity. from your log, it shows your have problem with connection..as well please try with change the name of Private Long id; to some other name and try once.

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate the variable itself, and not the getter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but please read my question again: I have already tried using the @Id decorator on the property/variable, and am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add *@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)* before your class definition to change the default access type from field to getter method

Like this:

```
import javax.persistence.AccessType;


@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Comment implements DomainEntity {

    private Long id;

    @Id
    @Column (name="id",unique=true,nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
            return this.id;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution to this, but from testing on another computer it was apparent that the version mismatch (another problem for another day) was not causing this. I deleted my workspace, my m2-cache, reimported the project and redownloaded all dependencies and now it suddenly works (Spring version problems and all).

Thank you all for your help.